# Is it possible to use icon classes in the CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, font-awesome

I have the expand and collapse accordion. I am using the font awesome plus and minus unicode in CSS to display the icons. I was wondering is it possible to use font awesome classes instead to display the icons?

```
CSS:
.accordion-toggle {
  background-color: #777;
}

.collapsed, .accordion-toggle:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question... the intended usage of Font Awesome _is_ through classes.

Comment: Hi @Studocwho, you can use font awesome with unicode as well. But i was wondering is there a way to use Font Awesome classes eg. <i class="far fa-plus"></i> <i class="far fa-minus"></i> in this scenario.

Comment: I see. Well you don't have to use specifically the `<i>`, you can use any element. So, in short yes, I believe you can. Then just toggle the classes on and off depending on the state of the accordion.

Answer (score 1):

Add additional class names `far fa-minus fa-plus` to elements with class `accordion-toggle`. Will be something like this "accordion-toggle far fa-minus fa-plus".  Then you can toggle class fa-plus

```
for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("fa-plus");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and it does not seem to work.

Comment: Remove `.accordion-toggle:after` class from your styles

Comment: It's still not working. Also the FA icons are part of the <i>.
 E.g: <i class="fal fa-plus"></i> <i class="fal fa-minus"></i> 
Ref: https://fontawesome.com/icons/plus?style=regular.

Comment: I have tried what you suggested, but I am not sure where the <i> classes go in my cshtml , as it is structured differently. Please see this: https://jsfiddle.net/cliffeee/cj8bv6qn/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it with both way using Unicode and using font awesome class.

As you told I have done it using font awesome class.

Please open codepen link : https://codepen.io/prakashrajotiya/pen/VwZyryj

```
.collapsed .fa-minus{
display:none;
}
.collapsed .fa-plus{
 display:inline-block;
}
.fa-plus{
display:none;
}
```